# How to optimize response.redirect in ASP.net

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

We know when we call `HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("http://tvrowdy.in");` It throw an exception. Can we do it this way(working fine). Need suggestions and improvements.

```
public static void ReferToPage(string strPageName)
{
    try
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(strPageName, false);
    }
    catch
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This question is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad, or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. For help clarifying this question so that it can be reopened, see the FAQ. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq#close

Comment: The code that you show is pointless, because sending `false` as the second parameter keeps the `Redirect` method from throwing an exception. There will never be any exception to catch (unless you call it too late so that the redirection is not possible any more).

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend against using 'catch-all' blocks unless absolutely necessary.

[`Response.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx) always throws a `ThreadAbortedException` by design (like it or not), unless you pass in the `false` for the second parameter.

> If you specify true for the `endResponse` parameter, this method calls the `End` method for the original request, which throws a `ThreadAbortException` exception when it completes. This exception has a detrimental effect on Web application performance, which is why passing false for the `endResponse` parameter is recommended.

Any other exceptions it throws indicate a invalid parameter or bad program state. You probably don't want to just ignore these errors and move on as though nothing has happened. I recommend you just do this:

```
public static void ReferToPage(string strPageName)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect(strPageName, false);
}
```

Comment: Would removing try catch block impact on performance?

Comment: @vikas It won't impact performance at all. Catch-all blocks are just bad practice.